# Angular 2 turn on compatibility mode

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to generate custom theme for Angular Material 2.
But the tutorial that is provided by Angula 2 team and includes this code for scss file:

```
@import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_all-theme';
@include mat-core(); $primary: mat-palette($mat-orange, 800);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 600, A100, A400);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 600);
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

generates CSS classes with prefix **.mat-** that is as I believe material v1 notation of elements?

So I decided to use mat-card and other components, but when I do so the angular 2 gives me this error

> The "mat-" prefix cannot be used out of ng-material v1 compatibility mode.

any help how to 
A) turn on compatibility mode 
B) generate themes another way?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming ?

Comment: @smnbbrv - this guide produces css, containing mat- prefixed classes, but material 2 is md- prefixed. How this is going to work?

Comment: @Obikson Actually, from the recent [changelog for angular material2 (2.0.0-beta.2)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-from-beta1), it states that the prefix has changed because they don't want the styles between AngularJS Material and Angular Material2 to conflict. *Thus, this is only for styles, not for elements*

Comment: So for elements, you should put `<md-card>content here</md-card>` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

### **Update:**

As of 2.0.0-beta.11, the `md-` prefix has been deprecated completely and the `mat-` prefix should be used moving forward.

---

If you're using a version lower than 2.0.0-beta.11, then this will **only** be an issue if your project is using *AngularJS Material* side-by-side with *Angular Material 2*.

If you aren't using *AngularJS Material* in your project, just go with using the `md-` prefix and you won't have compatibility issues (aka, CSS collisions).

---

**Solution:**

If your project is using *AngularJS Material* AND *Angular 2 Material*, AND you need to avoid CSS collisions:

Import `NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode` into your application's root module.

```
import { NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode } from '@angular/material'

@NgModule({
    ...,
    imports: [NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then use the `md-` prefix for *Angularjs Material* elements and the `mat-` prefix for *Angular Material 2* elements.

---

Compatibility mode for `@angular/material` allows components (prefixed with `md-`) to exist side-by-side with AngularJS Material components without any CSS collisions.

When enabled, compatibility mode forces all template APIs to use the prefix `mat-` instead of `md-`. This will prevent any CSS from *AngularJS Material* from affecting the components in `@angular/material`.

Documentation for this found [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/compatibility-mode.md).

Comment: Note that beta.11 has deprecated the "md" prefix completely and uses "mat" moving forward: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix. This affects all class names, properties, inputs, outputs, and selectors (CSS classes were changed back in February). The "md" prefixes will be removed in the next beta release.

Comment: @Splaktar what does 'CSS classes were changed back in Feb..' mean? Does this mean CSS classes can still use 'md'?

Comment: It means that the mat- prefix was already available for CSS classes in February, now the mat- prefix is everywhere. md- prefix is being deprecated everywhere. The prefix fixer tool makes the migration quite easy though.